# Is "ref=" the only directive that tells an XML schema to treat a global as a reference?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am going through an XML tutorial right now and while I think that I understand the concept of a "reference", I am trying to understand the advantage of using it.

If I look at the example given by the tutorial:

[image]

The only difference between a reference element (e.g. "Person") and an "embedded" (?) element is that the element that uses it, uses the `ref=` instead of `name=`.

Since both the referenced element and the non-referenced element are global and avoid duplication by defining a complex type, what is is that makes a referenced element what it is?

Answer (score 0):

Using local elements (non-global elements with a name attribute) allows you to have different types for the same element depending on where it occurs, for example project/status might have different validation rules than person/status. It can also be used simply for readability, though there are disadvantages: local elements cannot be reused, and cannot appear in substitution groups.

I tend to use local elements only for simple elements (elements having a simple type), and make all complex elements global.